# Keep the keyboard open for an HTML chat program on Android?

Tags: android, html, chrome-for-android

I'm building an HTML5 chat program which has an input field and submit button at the bottom of the page.

On Chrome for Android, when the user taps the field, the soft keyboard slides up, and the user can enter a message. Once the user taps "Go", however, the keyboard disappears, and then they have to click the field again to bring the keyboard up. This is annoying.

Is there a way to force the soft keyboard to stay open?

If it helps, I'm using jQuery to bind to the `submit` event for the form.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to change the input into a textarea and style it to look just like the input element.  That way the keyboard remains open when the user presses enter. It at least works on chrome for android for me.